Computing p-value using bootstrap bias-corrected and accelerated (BCa) confidence intervals - R
The boot.pval package throws an error when computing BCa p values. This suggested fix seems to work but I am unsure if this correct. The fix was suggested more than two years ago without having being accepted yet. Already checked this question on StackExchange but there is no guidance on BCa concretely. In the code below I show the problem and the suggested fix with the function boot.pval2 .
Are there other ways (packages, etc.) to compute bootstrap BCa p-values?
library(boot.pval)
library(boot)
# BCA not working

ratio <- function(d, w) sum(d$x * w)/sum(d$u * w)

city.boot <- boot(
  city, 
  ratio, 
  R = 99, 
  stype = "w",
  sim = "ordinary")

boot.pval(city.boot, 
           type = 'bca')

# throws error: 
# Error in if (any(ints)) out[inds[ints]] <- tstar[k[inds[ints]]] :
#   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

# adjusted based on suggested fix:   
# alpha_seq <- seq(pval_precision, 1-pval_precision, pval_precision)

# adjusted function:

boot.pval2 <- function(boot_res,
                       type = "perc",
                       theta_null = 0,
                       pval_precision = NULL,
                       ...)
{
  if(is.null(pval_precision)) { pval_precision = 1/boot_res$R }
  
  # Create a sequence of alphas:
  alpha_seq <- seq(pval_precision, 1-pval_precision, pval_precision)
  
  # changed above from alpha_seq <- seq(1e-16, 1-1e-16, pval_precision)
  
  # Compute the 1-alpha confidence intervals, and extract
  # their bounds:
  ci <- suppressWarnings(boot::boot.ci(boot_res,
                                       conf = 1- alpha_seq,
                                       type = type,
                                       ...))
  
  bounds <- switch(type,
                   norm = ci$normal[,2:3],
               basic = ci$basic[,4:5],
                   stud = ci$student[,4:5],
               perc = ci$percent[,4:5],
                   bca = ci$bca[,4:5])
  
  # Find the smallest alpha such that theta_null is not contained in the 1-alpha
  # confidence interval:
  alpha <- alpha_seq[which.min(theta_null >= bounds[,1] & theta_null <= bounds[,2])]
  
  # Return the p-value:
  return(alpha)
}


boot.pval2(city.boot, 
           type = 'bca')

# result:
# 0.01010101

One issue that could be related is that BCa bootstrap interval requires at least as many iterations as the number of observations. See here and here.
